# What does save(flush: true) do in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I had to use this recently in order to get a correct mongo save, but can't find anywhere (even in the mongo documentation) what it does. Can anyone explain it to me, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `save(flush: true)` all data in your session will be persisted  *immediately* to the database.

If you do not use not use the option `flush:true`, the data will only be recorded to get saved at the next flush and your data gets persisted in the database when the session is flushed, but it's not guarenteed to be immediatly (at the time of your save call) persisted.

The time to flush the session is automatically determined to optimize the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Having trouble understanding the last sentence "the time to flush the session is automatically determined to optimize the performance" what does that mean?

Comment: @flyingflamingo That means that the database chooses a time to flush as it sees best and you have no control over it. If there will be more calls of save in short periods of time it buffers these saves and at a time its algorithm thinks is appropriate these writes are persisted to disk. Without `flush:true` mongodb waits for a critical mass of changes until it actually does the writes.